Python Natasha all None
MyCode:
from natasha import Segmenter, NewsEmbedding, NewsNERTagger, Doc

segmenter = Segmenter()
emb = NewsEmbedding()
ner_tagger = NewsNERTagger(emb)

text = "Какая погода в Москве?"

doc = Doc(text)

doc.segment(segmenter)

print(f"Spans: {doc.spans}")
print(f"Text: {doc.text}")

if doc.spans:
    print("Segments found:")
    for span in doc.spans:
        print(span.text)
else:
    print("No segments found.")

Result: Spans: None and No segments found.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your Doc object isn't going to have a spans list until you call a method that actually creates that data - looks like .tag_ner() is what you'd have to use.  At the point where you're currently printing things out, the only attributes that are meaningful appear to be tokens and sents.

I've already done it on my own. Using another library - SpaCy
MyCode:
import spacy

# Загружаем модель spaCy для русского языка
nlp = spacy.load("ru_core_news_sm")

# Применяем spaCy для сегментации
doc = nlp("Какая погода в Москве?")

# Печатаем все найденные сущности
for ent in doc.ents:
   print(ent.text, ent.label_)

